# Add color to text in newform - custom list

Tags: 2007, custom-list

I am using Sharepoint 2007 (MOSS) and I would like to add color to the text of the titles in the new item page for my custom list.

Example:

Date:
Description:

These titles are in a particular color from the other headings

- I need to add color to specific headings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to change the color of all the heading, use CSS as suggested by user234429. For particular heading(s) you could use jQuery/javascript something similar to:

```
    var arr = ["Title *", "Date:", "Description:", "Body"];
    $(".ms-standardheader").each(function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).text().trim(), arr) >= 0) {
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where would I add this code?

Comment: Edit the page in SharePoint designer and add reference to jQuery if you don't have. Then insert the code within ContentPlaceHolderMain. Or if you opt to create a custom New Form, see the video tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zs5kHAddhzY

Answer (score 0):

If you open your page in IE Developer mode you can see that the titles of fields have a class of ms-standardheader. You could then edit the form page using SharePoint Designer 2007  tag with whatever style you want.

If the ms-standardheader class is to wide reaching, you can use the developer toolbar to look a bit higher up the DOM tree to find the ID of the form web part. An example of your script might look like this.

## WebPartWPQ2.ms-standardheader {color:red;}